# Can I unset PHP $_SESSION{} variables with a wildcard?

Tags: php, arrays, session, wildcard

Can I unset with wildcard?

I have a bunch of $_SESSION variables which all start with the same prefix. Rather than explicitly unset all, can I use a wildcard?

(the prefix remains the same, but depending on some conditions, the suffices vary, so I'd rathe not do it explicitly)

$_SESSION['abc_1']
$_SESSION['abc_2']
$_SESSION['abc_fish']
$_SESSION['abc_xyz']

$*SESSION['abc**']

Comment: Why don't you store those variables in an array instead? `$_SESSION['abc'] = array('fish'=>'foo','xyz'=>'bar');` You could unset that with a single unset call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop through the array and unset the right one...

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 3) == "abc") {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you may try to save correctly
like this:

```
$_SESSION['abc']['1']
$_SESSION['abc']['2']
$_SESSION['abc']['fish']
$_SESSION['abc']['xyz']
```

and then

```
unset($_SESSION['abc'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use a wildcard, but the easiest solution would be for you to walk through the Session array and check the keys with a regex expression. If it matches, unset :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with something like ...

```
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val) if (strpos($key,'abc_') !== false) unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

(I'd use strpos over substr because it's a bit faster)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {
    if (substr($k, 0, strlen('abc')) == 'abc')
        unset($_SESSION[$k]);
}
```